# How to concatenate string and html element with literals?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, template-literals

basically trying to combine some text with a link:

```
  const myText = `${t('privacyTxt')}` + `${<a>{t('privacyLink')}</a>}`;
```

result:

> To learn how we process your data, visit our[object Object]

What am I missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're trying to put JSX inside a template literal. It doesn't belong there.

If you're at the point of dealing with JSX, then everything should be done using JSX and not template literals.

```
const myText = <>
   {t('privacyTxt')}
   <a>
       {t('privacyLink')}
   </a>
</>;
```

Comment: Ohh man, how do you get 800K lol.. I'll give you an upvode for this . ;)